PWA "routes" Is Undefined
Trying to create a very simple ASP.NET core PWA, there doesnt seem to be many examples using .NET 8.0.
Steps as follows:

Created a brand new ASP.NET core app.  Using .NET 8.0.
Installed dotnet package WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA
Added a manifest file.
Added the two icons required to the images folder.
Added builder.Services.AddProgressiveWebApp();

The app runs and I get the option to install from Chrome which is great.   However the service-worker is unhappy, giving the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: routes is not defined
at serviceworker:11:42

Clicking on the error highlights the following service worker code:
 // Store core files in a cache (including a page to display when offline)
  function updateStaticCache() {
    return caches.open(version).then(function (cache) {
      return cache.addAll([offlineUrl, { routes }]);  // This line is highlighted.
    });
  }

Essentially I used this guide, but with .net 8.0:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/progressive-web-app-pwa-in-asp-net-core/
Is someone able to offer me some clues as to what is wrong with the service worker and why routes is undefined?

The answer for me was to manually load the manifest file:
program.cs:
// Register as a PWA application
builder.Services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions
{
    RegisterServiceWorker = true,
    RegisterWebmanifest = false,  // (Manually register in Layout file)
    Strategy = ServiceWorkerStrategy.NetworkFirst,
    OfflineRoute = "Offline.html"
});

layout:
@*Manually register the PWA Manifest*@
<link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json" />


But the manifest is not the file where the error is in, right? that is the serviceworker.js. How does loading the manifest manually fix the "route" is undefined error?

@Svenmarim Sorry I have no idea, just when I made the change it all seemed to work.  Perhaps I inadvertently changed something else?
